# Rollover IRA question

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, rollover

I have a quick question. I had 401K from 2 different past employers - Employer A and Employer B. I opened 2 Rollover IRA accounts - one in Brokerage A and another one in Brokerage B in early 2020. I did rollover my old 401k from employer A to Brokerage A and  from employer B to Brokerage B.

I read somewhere that I cannot do more than 1 rollover in a year. Is there something I need to worry about even if the rollover is from 2 different employers to 2 different brokerage firms?

Answer (score 3):

The [official rule](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/rollovers-of-retirement-plan-and-ira-distributions) is:

> You generally cannot make more than one rollover from the same IRA within a 1-year period. You also cannot make a rollover during this 1-year period from the IRA to which the distribution was rolled over.
>
> The one-per year limit does not apply to:
>
> - rollovers from traditional IRAs to Roth IRAs (conversions)
> - trustee-to-trustee transfers to another IRA
> - IRA-to-plan rollovers
> - plan-to-IRA rollovers
> - plan-to-plan rollovers

So if you do a ***trustee-to-trustee rollover*** (where the funds are sent directly from Brokerage A to Brokerage B, even if you have to route the check) you can do more than one in a year. Make sure you know all of the procedures for both firms before making the transfer so you don't make a mistake that will make the transfer taxable.

You can *still* do a non-exempt rollover, however, since the plan-to-IRA rollover's don't count toward the limit.

The "once a year" rule is probably intended to prevent people from taking multiple tax-free 60-day "loans" from their IRA since distributions can be paid back within 60 days with no tax or penalty.

Comment: I believe the one-per-year limit only applies when it involves a check made out directly to you. A lot of times rollovers involve paper checks, but they are made out to the receiving brokerage; this doesn't count against the limit.

Comment: @CraigW: Even if a check is made out to you and you rollover it by depositing it again, if it's a 401k-to-IRA rollover, it doesn't count towards the one per year limit, and you can do this as many times as you like in a year.